# How to compile ASP.NET 2.0 applications in medium trust

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using a .Net/C# script to upload XLS files and then dump in SQL SERVER.

It works great on Local server but doesnt on shared hosting space. Hosting is saying

"It seems you are using full trust in this application and we support medium trust on shared server, due to that reason you are getting this error message. Please recompile the application in medium trust and then check it."

I asked them how to recompile it Medium Trust, but they ask me to search on google, where i dont find any great help.

Shall i change something in web.config ?

Answer (score 0):

change the settings in your webconfig file..

```
<system.web>
    <trust level="Medium" originUrl="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

`ASP.NET Web applications to run in medium trust. If you host multiple applications on the same server, you can use code access security and the medium trust level to provide application isolation. By setting and locking the trust level in the machine-level Web.config file, you can establish security policies for all Web applications on the server. Running at medium trust with ASP.NET version 2.0 is easier than with ASP.NET version 1.1 because when using ASP.NET 2.0, you have access to Microsoft SQL Server databases at medium trust. Medium trust still provides a constrained environment for isolating applications from one another and from shared server resources. Medium trust applications have no registry access, no event log access, and no ability to use reflection. Web access is limited to the network address that you define in the <<trust/>> element, and file system access is limited to the application's virtual directory hierarchy. If medium trust policy is too restrictive, you can create and use a custom policy file.`

For more see a link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648344.aspx